# Galaxy S4 "Make Bug Report" dialog never initializes

Tags: android, galaxy

I am debugging an app on my Galaxy S4, I have enabled Developer Tools and have checked "Include bug reports in power menu". Once the app fails, I held down the power button and got the option to "Bug report". It notes that it might take some time, and I have done this before on my Nexus 7 and past Android phone.

The issue is, the Bug Report dialog to email the log+screenshot never shows. I've waited well over an hour, tested from the actual Developer Options menu to "Make bug report" (instead of through the power menu), and everything inbetween; patiently and multiple times with different approaches. I've searched far and wide for anyone reporting this same issue, or how long it takes for an S4 to collect this data, to no avail.

Has anyone else observed this issue? Would it be related to another installed app that is causing this to happen? Or does it take well over an hour to gather a log? I would suspect not.

Comment: "adb shell bugreport" is not enough?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly a solution for "Make Bug Report" problem, but you could use Samsung's custom bug report tool, [SysDump](http://widefide.com/mobile/samsung-galaxy-secret-codes)*, to get the logs:

1. Open the Dialer (Phone) and type `*#9900#`
2. Run logcat/dumpstate. Once done,
3. Copy to SD card

**Not my website and I'd not recommend trying all those codes, especially number 5.*

Answer (score 1):

The debug report is generated in the background. You will not see a popup screen, the notice displays in your notification bar. Drag down from the top of the screen to see your notifications and you will see "log report generated" when it is finished. It shouldn't take longer than a minute or two. When you click on that, you will have the option to share that report via the usual methods, such as email.